# What tools do people from Android Dev Team use to create Diagram and flowcharts?

Tags: android, eclipse, flowchart, diagrams

I really like the diagrams and flowcharts from the official developer.android.com website and I was wondering what was the name of the tools they were using. Anyone has an idea?

What is also a good tool for eclipse to create such things ?

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

[image: An example of a sequence diagram]

Comment: why won't you ask them? this question seems out of topic to me. vote to close.

Comment: That's really rude! Why is it out of topic ? what about my question about an equivalent eclipse tool ?

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you. I really think you should ask them, and as this is the main part of your question (including the title) I think it's off-topic.

Comment: I dont know what Google uses. These are documentation dudes who have access to the best tools Corel, Adobe. Microsoft Visio too is really really good that developers can use. A free alternative can be Dia on ubuntu. And I too believe this question is out of context, you have not done any research before posting a question here. And its not rude to moderate and control quality of questions.

Comment: StackOverflow > Faq > What kind of questions can I ask here? > Software tools commonly used by programmers... So asking about tools to produce flowcharts and diagram about a program is definitely not off topic. I did a search on flowcharts / diagram tools and found some answers about tools in general, but I wanted to know what was used to produce such charts and what was available on eclipse to produce them. The fact that it's google is not the point of my question. They use to rely on standard tools made me think it should have been something well known. Anyway thank u for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found it. It's a commercial web app called lucidchart. Will stay with Dia.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at DRAKON Editor. It generates Java code from diagrams.

http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Rykkin, will download and have a look. :)